Not getting expected results when loading tensorflowjs model
Followed this guide to create a tensorflow.js neural network https://medium.com/@GeorgePerry/finding-intent-to-buy-from-instagram-comments-with-tensorflow-js-3f764c132be7
It works prefectly until I save the model and try to load it again. When loaded from file output has changed.
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const use = require('@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder');

const comments =  require('./data/input-training.json')
const comment_testing = require('./data/input-test.json')

const encodeData = data => {
  const sentences = data.map(comment => comment.text.toLowerCase()); 
  const trainingData = use.load()
      .then(model => {
          return model.embed(sentences)
              .then(embeddings => {
                  return embeddings;
              });
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('Fit Error:', err));

  return trainingData
};

const outputData = tf.tensor2d(comments.map(comment => [
  comment.intent === 0 ? 1 : 0,
  comment.intent === 1 ? 1 : 0
]));

const model = tf.sequential();

// Add layers to the model
model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [512],
    activation: 'sigmoid',
    units: 2,
}));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({
    inputShape: [2],
    activation: 'sigmoid',
    units: 2,
}));

model.add(tf.layers.dense({ 
    inputShape: [2],
    activation: 'sigmoid',
    units: 2,
}));

// Compile the model
model.compile({
    loss: 'meanSquaredError',
    optimizer: tf.train.adam(.06), // This is a standard compile config
});

function run() {
  Promise.all([
      encodeData(comments),
      encodeData(comment_testing)
  ])
  .then(data => {
      const {
          0: training_data,
          1: testing_data,
      } = data;

      model.fit(training_data, outputData, { epochs: 200 })
          .then(history => {
              model.predict(testing_data).print();
              model.save('file://./model')
                  .then(() => console.log('Model Saved!'));
          });
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Prom Err:', err));
};

// Call function
run();

This code outputs working classification for my test data.
When loading with below code, output is wrong.
const tf = require('@tensorflow/tfjs');
const tfnode = require('@tensorflow/tfjs-node');
const use = require('@tensorflow-models/universal-sentence-encoder');

const comments =  require('./data/input-training.json')
const comment_testing = require('./data/input-test.json')

var model;
async function loadM() {
  model = await tf.loadLayersModel('file://./model/model.json');
  console.log('Model Loaded!');
}

const encodeData = data => {
  const sentences = data.map(comment => comment.text.toLowerCase()); 
  const trainingData = use.load()
      .then(model => {
          return model.embed(sentences)
              .then(embeddings => {
                  return embeddings;
              });
      })
      .catch(err => console.error('Fit Error:', err));

  return trainingData
};

function run() {
  Promise.all([
      encodeData(comments),
      encodeData(comment_testing)
  ])
  .then(data => {
      const {
          0: training_data,
          1: testing_data,
      } = data;
      model.predict(testing_data).print();
      
  })
  .catch(err => console.log('Prom Err:', err));
};

// Call function
loadM();
run();

Trainging data is about 5000 rows similar to below.
[
    {
        "text": "Im looking to buy a new X from Y",
        "intent": "buy"
    },
    {
        "text": "I have a few items that could be of intrest to you",
        "intent": "sell"
    }
]

Am I loading it wrong, or do I have to process/encode data someother way when loaded from file?
Model is not converted with tensorflowjs_converter, because I cannot figure out if its necessary. Does all models have to be converted?
